# A way to filter "remote" yet US/Canada-only jobs out

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I'd like a way to filter US/Canada-only jobs from remote jobs listing. I often tend to avoid seeing jobs with salary given in USD, but not every offer provides such information. Those jobs are also not really location-independent.

BTW: Is that some law limitation in Canada and US prohibiting companies to cooperate with people from other parts of the world even on B2B basis or just their demands to be in a similar time zone?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I _think_ the reason some companies do this is because a company can't technically employ someone in a country where they don't have an official corporate presence. For those companies which do employ people all around the world, I believe it's common for it to be consultant/client relationship for the purposes of the law.

Comment: Beyond legal concerns, there are very real practical concerns over communication. Not being in similar time zones makes it very difficult to have conference calls. Conference calls are further hampered by poor common language skills or difficult-to-understand accents. Non real-time communications have come a long way, but they still have significant limitations. It’s workable for limited consultant-style collaboration, where the remote party works on clearly desgnated tasks easily broken up into “chunks”. It doesn’t work so well for true employees with a variety of responsibilities.

Comment: Granted, limiting the candidate pool to US/Canada is definitely doing it wrong. Instead, the actual requirements should be clearly stated: working hours availability in UTC, language skills, etc. If you’re a night-owl living in Japan with excellent English skills, you’d be a great remote worker for any US company.

Comment: Related with the second part of your question, you might want to read the answer from this Money.SE question: [Working as a European self-employed for an USA company](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/working-as-a-european-self-employed-for-an-usa-company)

Comment: @CodyGray I know about people in China that basically live in the US, while in China. They sleep, eat and do stuff in the US timezone.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Jobs feature no longer exists.